# Telnet into Red Hat?

Tags: redhat, telnet

How do I enable telnet for a Red Hat Linux system?

Comment: can you clarify?  do you mean to telnet into a red hat system or to enable telnet on a red hat system so you can then takes steps to telnet into it?

Comment: Are you sure you want Telnet? Telnet is a insecure protocol, whereas something like SSH works a lot better and is more secure.

Comment: What, other than it being a bad idea, makes this "not a real question" and thus deserving of being closed?

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is a specific reason you need telnet, I would recommend using SSH over telnet.  Everything is transmitted unencrypted via telnet, so it is possible to sniff that traffic and pull out passwords.

With that said, to enable it, you first need the telnet server installed

> sudo yum -y install telnet-server

This should pick up the xinetd package which is also required.

By default, even after you install the package it will be disabled.  You need to edit */etc/xinetd.d/telnet*
and change the line that says **disable=yes** to **disable=no**

Then you will need to start xinetd with

> sudo /sbin/service xinetd start

If you have a firewall enabled, you will need to allow traffic on port 23.

Answer (score 1):

Redhat has telnet disabled by default for a good reason - it's a crappy clear-text protocol left over from the 1980s. It would be best if you left it disabled.

It will however have an SSH server started, which is the modern equivalent of telnet. You'll likely be able log into it that way - use PuTTY on Windows, or `ssh` client on any other system.

If you're after something more, and actually *require* a telnet server, please explain a bit more.

Comment: The telnet client is still a great utility for testing whether certain ports are reachable on a given machine. Just don't use the server.